# Add Slider Extension in Opencart?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am Creating a Opencart Page with 1500 products. In homepage I want

> Slider Extension For Products With Time interval. .

How can i Add the extension . .

Help me Out Here. . For Extension Code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a slider extension exits in the admin panel.
Goto

```
Extension ->Modules -> Banner
```